# The C# project cannot access the deployed server when connecting to the Webservice service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I make a C#application based on the SQL database. I know that the database service needs to be deployed on the website, and others can access my database remotely.

Then I deployed a webservice on the website according to the Internet method, but the C#program could not access the database.

This is the code：

webservice1.asmx.cs：

```
[WebService(Namespace = "localhost")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    DBOperation dbOperation = new DBOperation();
}
```

DBOperation:

```
public class DBOperation : IDisposable
{
    public static SqlConnection sqlCon;      
    private String ConServerStr = @"Data Source=DAWN\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial Catalog=KYQuery;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456";       
    public DBOperation()
    {
        if (sqlCon == null)
        {
            sqlCon = new SqlConnection();
            sqlCon.ConnectionString = ConServerStr;
            sqlCon.Open();
        }
    }       
   
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (sqlCon != null)
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
            sqlCon = null;
        }
    }

}
```

webservice:

```
        ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient ws = new ServiceReference1.WebService1SoapClient();
        SqlConnection sqlcn = new SqlConnection();
        string connectionString = @"Data Source = DAWN\MSSQLSERVER2; Initial Catalog = KYQuery;User ID = sa; Password = 123456";
        sqlcn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        SqlCommand sqlcm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcm.Connection = sqlcn;
        sqlcm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcm.CommandText = "select * from KYQuery";
        sqlcn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlcm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        sqlcm.Dispose();
        if (sqlcn != null)
        {
            sqlcn.Dispose();
            sqlcn.Close();
        }

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I don't know where there is a problem. I hope you can help it. I am very grateful.

Comment: Can the web server reach the database server?

Comment: @DanielA.White It's OK.

Comment: You could "could not access the database" - how? What is the exact exception details? Provide the full exception details, including the message, the stack trace, and any inner exceptions.

Comment: Hi, you do have some problems with your code. But before giving a specific solution, you need to answer two questions: 1. Can the C# program connect to the database before you deploy the database to the server? 2. Can other programs work normally on the same server?

Comment: The database can be accessed locally, and the server should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBOperation dbOperation = new DBOperation();`is not used in this way

You need to replace `DBOperation dbOperation = new DBOperation();` with the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable Select()
    {
         DBOperation dbOperation = new DBOperation();
     SqlConnection sqlcn = new SqlConnection();
        string connectionString = @"Data Source = DAWN\MSSQLSERVER2; Initial Catalog = KYQuery;User ID = sa; Password = 123456";
        sqlcn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        SqlCommand sqlcm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcm.Connection = sqlcn;
        sqlcm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcm.CommandText = "select * from KYQuery";
        sqlcn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlcm;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        sqlcm.Dispose();
        if (sqlcn != null)
        {
            sqlcn.Dispose();
            sqlcn.Close();
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have a problem with my webservice, but it's too late